# When an immutable reference to a mutable reference to a value outside the scope is returned, why is the mutable reference dropped when the scope ends?

Tags: rust, mutable, dereference, borrowing

```
fn main() {
    // block1: fails
    {
        let mut m = 10;

        let n = {
            let b = &&mut m;
            &**b // just returning b fails
        };

        println!("{:?}", n);
    }

    // block2: passes
    {
        let mut m = 10;

        let n = {
            let b = &&m;
            &**b // just returning b fails here too
        };

        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
}
```

**block1** fails with the error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:22
   |
7  |             let b = &&mut m;
   |                      ^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
8  |             &**b // just returning b fails
9  |         };
   |         - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
...
12 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
```

Am I correct in assuming that the inner immutable reference is extended beyond the **block2** scope, whereas in **block1**, the inner mutable reference is always dropped even if there is an outer reference to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sufficient here to think of a mutable borrow as a non-`Copy` struct (`S` in the snippets below) which takes ownership of the referenced value. This model represents the exclusive nature of a mutable borrow.

Reasoning based on this model: In block2 `n` is a reference to the original `m`, while in block1 `n` would end up being a reference to a copy of `m` owned by the mutable borrow. In both blocks the inner reference is dropped at the end of the let-block, but only in block1 this causes a problem, because in block1 the target of the reference for `n` is still owned by the inner reference when this inner reference is dropped.

```
struct S { m: i32 }
let mut m = 10;

let n = {
    let s = S { m };
    let b = &s;
    &(*b).m
}; // s is dropped

println!("{:?}", n);
```

In the snippet above `s` takes ownership of a copy of `m`. The reference `n` would point to that copy of `n` which is dropped when `s` is dropped - not allowed. If `m` was non-Copy, `m` would be moved into `s`, which would have the same implications.

In block2 the original `m` is borrowed directly without copying it. If you force a copy, you will get the same error as for block1:

```
let mut m = 10;

let n = {
    let m2 = m;
    let mut a = &m2;
    let b = &a;
    &**b
};

println!("{:?}", n);
```

Comment: What triggers `m` to be copied in __block1__ ? I mean clearly in this case `fn main() {
    let mut m:i32 = 10;
    let n = {
        let b = &mut m;
        *b = 12;
        &*b
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", n);
}` , it is not. Is the copied triggered because of outer reference?

Comment: A temporary mutable reference will always take the ownership (copy/move)  of the value it is pointing to?

Comment: I can see the parallel between `&mut` and `S`, but this can't be the whole story. For one thing, [block1 will work if you remove the extra layer of `&`](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=80efb0bfa11cccf7add174435a74c4c5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), whereas the version with `S` will still fail to compile

Comment: block1 with only 1 `&` (i.e `&mut`) is working because there is no copy (no ownership) involved and there is no temporary (akin to rvalue?) here, I guess. So that's why I asked is the ownership taken because it is a temporary ref. (incase of `&&mut` i mean)

Comment: @soupybionics Obviously, `S` is too simplistic to model the full semantics of `&mut`. My guess is that the outer reference forces the compiler to base its reasoning on some stricter model for `&mut` which is closer to `S` and therefore cannot guarantee that the code is safe, while in the case where the outer reference is missing the compiler can make advanced use of its knowledge about `&mut` to infer that the code is indeed safe.

Comment: @Calculator The `temporary value does not live long enough` is referring to `&mut m` and not just `m` (My guess based on the error message having `^^^^^^` underlining the whole of `&mut m` and not just `m`). So it is the `&mut` which is the _temporary value_ pointing to `m` without taking the ownership (no move/copy).  If `&mut` does take the ownership, shouldn't [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4c46ed68f0695c9e6f3ae8266a7ea385&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) fail to compile then ? It passes.